# Do I need foomatic printer drivers?

Tags: printing, pdf, cups-lpd, foomatic

I just installed a print to pdf back-end for cups, and it gave the warning that foomatic printer modules would need to be removed. Do I need foomatic printer drivers, for when i want to print to physical devices?

What am I giving up here? Will I be having other problems in the near future for having removed foomatic printer support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only package which is pre-installed on your system is `foomatic-db-compressed-ppds`. `ubuntu-desktop` depends on `foomatic-db-compressed-ppds`, but the removal of `foomatic-db-compressed-ppds`, which also removes `ubuntu-desktop`, doens't destroys your system, as `ubuntu-desktop` is only a meta-package.

> This package contains all PPD files which can be generated from the
>   Foomatic database as one small compressed archive. This reduces the
>   disk space consumption compared to the Foomatic XML database vastly
>   and in addition makes listing of all available PPDs and extracting the
>   needed PPD much faster than using the Foomatic XML database.

Both packages, `cups-pdf` and `printer-driver-cups-pdf`, don't depends on `foomatic-db-compressed-ppds`.

---

On the other side, if you need any foomatic package later by a dependency, let's resolve this problem later, **if** there is any.

Comment: +1 for: "let's cross that bridge when we meet it..."